# bash: alembic: command not found when migration

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, alembic

I'm trying to make migration to create Tables in my heroku-postgres-database.

I'm using this command:

`heroku run "alembic upgrade head"`

I got an error after 2 seconds:

**`Running alembic upgrade head on ⬢ my-fastapi-test... up, run.9583 (Free)`**
**`bash: alembic: command not found`**

I don't found any answers. Where is the problem?
Here is my alembic.ini and env.py files. I'm doing a freeCodeCamp.org FastAPI tutorial and I stucked with this problem.

File `alembic.ini`

```
# A generic, single database configuration.
[alembic]
# path to migration scripts
script_location = alembic

# template used to generate migration files
# file_template = %%(rev)s_%%(slug)s

# sys.path path, will be prepended to sys.path if present.
# defaults to the current working directory.
prepend_sys_path = .

# timezone to use when rendering the date within the migration file
# as well as the filename.
# If specified, requires the python-dateutil library that can be
# installed by adding `alembic[tz]` to the pip requirements
# string value is passed to dateutil.tz.gettz()
# leave blank for localtime
# timezone =

# max length of characters to apply to the
# "slug" field
# truncate_slug_length = 40

# set to 'true' to run the environment during
# the 'revision' command, regardless of autogenerate
# revision_environment = false

# set to 'true' to allow .pyc and .pyo files without
# a source .py file to be detected as revisions in the
# versions/ directory
# sourceless = false

# version location specification; This defaults
# to alembic/versions.  When using multiple version
# directories, initial revisions must be specified with --version-path.
# The path separator used here should be the separator specified by "version_path_separator" below.
# version_locations = %(here)s/bar:%(here)s/bat:alembic/versions

# version path separator; As mentioned above, this is the character used to split
# version_locations. The default within new alembic.ini files is "os", which uses os.pathsep.
# If this key is omitted entirely, it falls back to the legacy behavior of splitting on spaces and/or commas.
# Valid values for version_path_separator are:
#
# version_path_separator = :
# version_path_separator = ;
# version_path_separator = space
version_path_separator = os  # Use os.pathsep. Default configuration used for new projects.

# the output encoding used when revision files
# are written from script.py.mako
# output_encoding = utf-8

sqlalchemy.url = postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:mypassword@localhost:5432/My FastAPI Database


[post_write_hooks]
# post_write_hooks defines scripts or Python functions that are run
# on newly generated revision scripts.  See the documentation for further
# detail and examples

# format using "black" - use the console_scripts runner, against the "black" entrypoint
# hooks = black
# black.type = console_scripts
# black.entrypoint = black
# black.options = -l 79 REVISION_SCRIPT_FILENAME

# Logging configuration
[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembic

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console
qualname =

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[logger_alembic]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = alembic

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %H:%M:%S
```

File `env.py`

```
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context
from app.models import Base
from app.config import settings

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config
config.set_main_option(
    "sqlalchemy.url", f'postgresql+psycopg2://{settings.database_username}:{settings.database_password}@'
                      f'{settings.database_hostname}:{settings.database_port}/{settings.database_name}')

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = Base.metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

Comment: Is `alembic` declared as a dependency in your `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`?

Comment: Yes. ```alembic==1.7.7``` in  requirements.txt

Comment: And that's committed and deployed? Do you see it being installed during the build process? Do you also have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`?

Comment: Yes it is.  But I don't have `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`. Is it necessary?

Comment: I have `Procfile` and in file : `web: uvicorn app.main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-5000}`

Comment: No, you only need a `requirements.txt` _or_ a `Pipfile`. But the latter takes precedence if it exists. A common problem is to have both and add dependencies to the requirements file only, which means they won't be installed.

Comment: Yes, I have only `requirements.txt`. I would also add that command `alembic upgrade head` works with my app. Maybe it's a problem with heroku? That's why I added env.py and alembic.ini to the post. I can add others files if needed.